# Mobile Application Peer-to-Peer Communication

Tags: networking, sms, communication

I ask the question because I don't even know how to ask it to my dear Google friend, and when I try to ask, no proper answer returns.

So I want to build a native app (let's call it TheApp) which deals with some data from users (name, location, etc. and some specific data created and used within the app). I don't want to centralise TheApp's users' data in my servers, I want the user's data to stay in the user phone, and find a way to communicate it to somebody else's phone without going through any kind of server.
I thought it looked like how the SMS works : there are messages on two phones and there isn't any server in between stocking or intercepting the messages, is it ?

So the direct question is : can we make two (or more) phones exchange pieces of data with no server in between ? Can we do it either through cellphones network, either through 3g/4g/5g, either through internet ?

Sorry if the question seems odd or trivial, or if I use wrong words to describe it, but I have no knowledge in the field as you can see...

Thanks !

Comment: SMS does involve a server. It's a store and forward messaging system. The server is called an SMSC (short message service centre).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMS is an overkill here. Take a look at [WebRTC Data Channels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/WebRTC_data_channels), which is a technology for peer-to-peer communication. It has native iOS and Android support and, if you happen to need it later, even users running desktop browsers will be able to communicate with mobile users.

[WebRTC on iOS](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/)

[WebRTC on Android](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/)

Comment: thanks for your help mate, I mark you response as accepted (because my bounty stops very soon) but I didn't test it yet, so maybe I'll comment back later. Anyway, good or bad, you provided what I wanted : a clue ! thanks